# How to fix virtuemart?

Tags: joomla

When I am trying to configure shop details *(virtueamart)*, I am receiving this message every time

```
JUser: :_load: Unable to load user with ID: 830 and can not save the changes.

Virtueamart :
You have the latest version
2.0.22c
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to user id `830` is mismatched in `DB` .

that is from `#__users` tables this 830 is removed and some other tables this user id exists.
Please check all the tables that related to user data like, `#__user_details,#__virtuemart_userinfo, order info etc.`

Also make sure this user id removed from all user data related tables. This may happen due to manual removal of users data from tables.

Other wise you have to create an entry in user table with this id.

Hope its get fixed..